# How to remove shadow on a UIToolbar button icon?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, shadow

How would one remove the shadow of an icon on a UIBarButtonItem on a UIToolbar?

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the standard way that a `UIBarButtonItem` is rendered when you use one of the system items to create the button.

If you want a different appearance, you need to use your own image and a `UIButton`. The create the `UIBarButtonItem` with the `initWithCustomView:` method. You will lose the "glow" effect when you do this. To get it back you need to set the `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` property of the `UIButton`.

Comment: I guess I do need to use the custom view method. Also, thanks for the tip about re-enabling the glow if I do this!